# org.opencv.text package missing?

Tags: java, opencv, east-text-detector

in the [OpenCV Java documentation (3.4.10)](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.10/javadoc/index.html)

there is a org.opencv.text package. But in my windows installation of the OpenCV 3.4.10 there is no text package and by the brief view I can say, that there are couple of others missing too. 
Why is that? How can I get a version with all packages/classes included?

Comment: Can you post how or where did you get the windows library(the jar file)?

Comment: Sure. It is standard self-extracting archive downloaded from https://opencv.org/releases/